# Searching on array of dictionary for boolean values

Tags: arrays, dictionary, vb6

I have structure like

```
Private wells() As Dictionary
```

I need to know if key 'active' which exists in each dictionary is at least once set to true.

Is there any way to archive it without looping? something like

```
dim hasActive as boolean
hasActive = wells()["active"] = true
```

for now I'm looping but app was written 15 years ago, and there are many more records and many more dictionary keys added to each of them, so loop started to take more time than it is sensible to wait.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No.

It really sounds like you should be considering another data structure or even a database at this point.  Simple single-key/value-pair technology like Dictionary has its limitations.  "Arrays of Dictionary" feels pretty bizarre just to start with.

A fabricated ADO Recordset makes a handy "super collection" object that can have multiple values/columns, and you can index fields that require frequent use as keys via the "Optimize" dynamic property.

Comment: Sounds fair enough, I found that it would be easier to get additional dictionary from database containing just distinct result and go with this. But if I could design it from scratch I would go to disconnected or fabricated recordset instead of array of dictionaries. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly, but you could easily write a class module that wraps your array of Dictionaries, and provides methods to let you manipulate those items.  The containing class could then also keep track of a count of Dictionaries where item "active" is True.  Those methods would increment the count when an "active" item is set True, and decrement the count when an active one is set to False. Then you can just inspect the count to know if any of the Dictionaries currently have an "active" item that's set to True.

Instantiate the array and dictionaries in Class_Initialize, and set the count to zero.  Provide methods to add and remove items, (along with any other methods you may need), and a property to tell you if any dictionary has its "active" item set to True.

Of course, this does mean that you'll have to change all of the code in the project to use your class rather than directly accessing the array and dictionaries.  I don't think that should be all that difficult, though.